# Unexpected bitwise operation result

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

Consider:

```
php > $a = 12; // 1100
php > echo ~$a;
-13
```

I would expect the inverse of `1100` to be either `0011` (direct) or `11110011` (an entire byte). That would give a result to either `3` or `243`. Whence cometh `-13`?

Again, for good measure, another unexpected result of the same type and explanation:

```
php > $b =  6; // 0110
php > echo ~$b;
-7
```

Why `-7`?

Comment: Why are you sparing out the minus in the shown results? Integers in PHP do not just occupy a byte, but usually a 32 or 64 bit word, and are signed.

Comment: I didn't even notice the minus signs there! I'm actually copying this from a less-than-ideal environment. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: AND the result with `0xf` (`1111`) so you get the answer you expect: `echo ~$b & 0xf`, it will cut the first 4 bits for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
<?php
$val = 6;

print "$val = ".decbin($val);
print "\n";
$val = ~$val;
print "$val = ".decbin($val);
```

It prints

```
6 = 110
-7 = 11111111111111111111111111111001
```

At first you have 110. As my php uses 32 bits, after inverting all the bits, we get this huge number. As the 1-st bit is 1, php interprets it as a negative value, stored, using two's-complement representation. To find out, the modulus of the negative value, stored in this notation, we

1. invert the digits:

110

1. add one to the result:

111

which gives us 7

So, the value is -7

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html

Answer (score 1):

> Why -7?

`6` is `00000000000000000000000000000110`, so `~6` is `~00000000000000000000000000000110`, and that's equal to `11111111111111111111111111111001`. Because a signed datatype is used, the first bit indicates whether the number is positive or negative (positive = `0` and negative = `1`). Because it is [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), you should convert the binary number to decimal using this way:

1. Invert the binary number. You get `00000000000000000000000000000110`
2. Convert `00000000000000000000000000000110` (a positive binary number) to a decimal number. You get `6`
3. Add `6` up with one: you get `7`
4. Make it negative: you get `-7`